# How the tau gallicum may have been pronounced?

Tags: phonetics, historical-linguistics

The so-called *tau gallicum* was a character used in Gaulish, written Đ, ð or even a Θ. Its name comes from the only commentary on it that we have, by Vergil (Appendix Vergiliana, Catalepton II, 4).

Every study I have read on Gaulish states that it was pronounced as the affricate [t͡s] or the reversed [s͡t]<sup>1</sup>, but there are occurrences of geminated *tau gallicum*, in the [Chamalières' lead](http://encyclopedie.arbre-celtique.com/plomb-de-chamalieres-2265.htm) and in [this epitaph](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/File:Tau_gallic_CourDOr_Metz_3147.jpg).

I am really not comfortable with a [t͡st͡s]`in *snIeððic* or *aððedillI*, so I wondered if there are others hypothesis for the pronunciation of this character. Maybe [Θ], since Θ and Greek Θ are obviously close, at least in writing.

--
<sub>1. See, for example, Lambert's *la langue gauloise* "The affricate /st/ in *snies-ti-c* is written striked d, as usual in Gaulish."</sub>

Comment: The existence of a double-ð does not necessarily imply that the affricate was released twice, any more than other doubled stops are released twice. More likely the stop portion of the affricate was geminated, but the affricate was only released once.

Comment: Why can’t *ðð* be a geminated [t͡s], e.g. [t͡s:] or perhaps [t͡:s]?

Comment: I think one of those comments ought be promoted to an answer.

Comment: @thdsmith: done :).

Comment: Interesting. By the way, it is unlikely that the Appendix Vergiliana was actually written by the man himself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The existence of a double-ð does not necessarily imply that the affricate was released twice, any more than other doubled stops are released twice. More likely the stop portion of the affricate was geminated, but the affricate was only released once. For comparison, consider modern Italian orthography, in which the letter *z* represents /ts/, but double *zz* is extremely common. This double letter does *not* indicate [t͡st͡s], but rather [t:s].

With that in mind, I see no reason to dispute the standard reconstruction of the tau gallicum. In particular, I find the suggestion that it could be [θ] to be very unlikely, given the available evidence.